# Play IQ data in the soundcard

Tags: fft, real-time, quadrature

I have short-wave digital receiver that send RP packets with IQ components over network depend of the RF frequency and passband. I need to work with the telephone passband (0.3 - 3.4 kHz). The task is:

Using ordinary notebook receive RTP packets in the real-time, extract IQ-data, build FFT, visualize it and then I need to playback this data on the ordinary soundcard.

Please, help me out. How can I do this quickly (in the short time)? Maybe prepared solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

If the spectrum of your I/Q samples is centered at zero then you'll have to perform either AM or FM demodulation before routing any real-valued audio samples to a sound card. For AM demodulation you'll need to implement a complex-input "envelope detector" which produces a real-valued audio signal riding on a DC bias. (In a few days check the web page:

www.dsprelated.com

for a blog of mine describing different envelope detectors.) That amplitude-biased audio signal then needs to be passed through a "DC blocking" filter (a highpass filter whose cutoff frequency is very close to zero Hz) and the output of that filter goes to your sound card.  From Chapter 13 of my DSP book, the most common DC blocking filters look like the following:

[image]

where alpha is a number close to, but less than, one.

Now if your I/Q signal (whose spectrum is centered at zero Hz) is an FM modulated signal there are two common ways to perform FM demodulation to produce a real-valued audio signal sequence.  One way is unpleasant because it requires the computation of arctangents and the other way is unpleasant because it requires you to perform divisions. Oleg, search the Internet for "digital FM demodulation" and you will be able to learn about those two different FM demodulation methods.

Comment: Hello Richard. Thank you for answer. Why a can't take sqrt(I^2 + Q^2)  as the value that I can pass to soundcard ???

Comment: I don't need to do any demodulation. I receive IQ data in the telephone band (from 0 Hz to 3400 Hz)............ I only need to playback this signal in a sound card and build FFT. But how to put IQ data to sound card??? I need to convert to real value....

Answer (score 3):

I'm replying to Oleg's recent comments here in an "Another Answer" block because the "add a comment" capability prevents me from providing a complete reply to Oleg. Here's my reply:

You *can* indeed take the sqrt(I^2 + Q^2). (That is one step in one method of AM demodulation.) But you realize that if you do so all of your computed sqrt samples will be positive-valued, right?  What you will have then is an "amplitude-biased audio signal" as I described in my above answer. Oleg, try these three things:

[1] Route just your real-valued 'I' signal to your sound card and see how the audio sounds.

[2] Compute the sqrt(I^2 + Q^2) and route that real-valued signal to your sound card and see how the audio sounds.

[3] Pass your sqrt(I^2 + Q^2) through a DC blocking filter (that I mentioned in my above answer), and then route that real-valued filter output signal to your sound card and see how the audio sounds.

Also, because you are working with a digital receiver I suggest you have a look at the envelope detectors at:

https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/938.php

Any one of those detectors can be used for AM demodulation (with a DC blocking filter, or course).